# Why does it fail to declare a class globally in c++ which is built to be a dll file?

Tags: c#, c++, tensorflow, dll

I'm working on a project which required a dll file for another program written in c# to use. Since I'm not very familiar with C++ and the details about C# calling function from dll...

**FIRST** - I wrote those functions I need in a the most basic way

-> composed of A.h, A.cpp, and run with the built file A.exe made from VS2015

**SECOND** -  I revise the code run successfully above to the format which made some functions can be called from c# through the dll file

-> composed of A.h, A.cpp, get a A.dll built from VS2015

**THIRD** - I test the dll file's function through a simple C# program

Since the code is going to be used on real-time inference(with tensorflow's model), so I wrote the part of model initializing in a function, and the inference part in another function. I made all the model's function a class(including ***initialize*** and ***inference***).

There are more than 1 model I use in the project, and the models won't be modified after they're initialized. Since they have to use in different functions, I decide to globalize each class(model).

```cpp
//file.h

class UnetInterface
{
public:
    UnetInterface(std::string model_path);

    int predict(cv::Mat srcImage, cv::Mat& dstimage);
private:
    ....
};


//file.cpp

//I put those class declaration outside functions to make them globally

UnetInterface A = UnetInterface(path1);
UnetInterface B = UnetInterface(path2);

UnetInterface::UnetInterface(string model_path)
{
    inp_tensor_name = "input_1:0";
    out_tensor_name = "conv2d_19/Sigmoid:0";
    std::cout << "UnetInerface-> " << model_path << std::endl;

    Status status_load = ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), model_path, &graphdef);
    std::cout << ">>>  initial model in InetInterface" << std::endl;
    if (!status_load.ok()) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Loading model failed..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << model_path << status_load.ToString() << "\n";
    }

    NewSession(SessionOptions(), &session);  //looks like it always stuck in here while initializing
    Status status_create = session->Create(graphdef);
    if (!status_create.ok()) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Creating graph in session failed.." << status_create.ToString() << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "----------- Successfully created session and load graph -------------" << std::endl;
    }

}

// initialization of those class objects
// this can speed up the speed of inference afterwards
void init()  
{
    A.predict(pic_1);
    B.predict(pic_2);
}

LIB_API void inference(pic)  // the function c# calling for each inference
{
    A.predict(pic_x);
    B.predict(pic_y);
}
```

The declaration above works fine in the FIRST way I mentioned above...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FkvQ.png

but if it's running in c# (the exe file shown below), it always stuck while initializing.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqZbh.png

I also tried the way of declaring the class in the .h file, and called them in the .cpp file, but the result is the same as the above method.

```cpp
// file.hpp
extern UnetInterface A = UnetInterface(path1);
extern UnetInterface A = UnetInterface(path2);
```

So I came up with another way, returning a struct of class after initializing.
However, I'm not very sure what is the correct way to make a struct of class, this is what I've done so far(with some errors I write as comment):

```
//file.h

struct Unets // The struct that stores initialized classes
{
    UnetInterface A;
    UnetInterface B;
};


//file.cpp

Unets init()  // initialization of those class objects
{
    Unets TT;  // error: 'Unets::Unets(void)':attempting to reference a deleted function
               // error: the default constructor of "Unets" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
    TT.A = UnetInterface(path1);
    TT.A.predict(pic1);
    TT.B = UnetInterface(path2);
    TT.B.predict(pic2);
    ...
    ...

    return TT;
}

LIB_API void inference(pic3)  // the function c# calling for each inference
{
    Unets TT2;  // error: the default constructor of "Unets" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
    TT2 = init();
    TT2.predict(pic3);
}
```

I don't know if it's necessary to re-declare the struct 'Unets' for every use of the function 'inference'. If it is, I think it's not a good idea to write like this, so I'm stuck in here...

To sum up, I want to know...

**1. Why the global class I declared as the FIRST way failed while running in c#?**

**2. Is the last method an option to work? If it is/isn't, any other suggestion on returning multiple initializing classes(model)?**

(Thanks in advance for finish reading my messy question description...

Any advise or help is appreciated :D )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to decouple your issue here as I see there are two items. First, about running your code from the Dll with global static initialization. Second, about running your code with your structure for TensorFlow inference.

About the first item, this *should* be working. You can try these by running them with a simple task (for example, console print out) but not tensorflow initializations (comment them out). The second item, in your case, it *could* be that the GPU is occupied by the first exe, hence, the second exe was waiting.

**Update**

Some suggestion for you code:

```
//file.cpp
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<Unets> init()  // initialization of those class objects
{
    //Unets TT;  // error: 'Unets::Unets(void)':attempting to reference a deleted function
               // error: the default constructor of "Unets" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
    auto TT = std::make_shared<Unets>();

    ...
    ...

    return TT;
}

LIB_API void inference(pic3)  // the function c# calling for each inference
{
    //Unets TT2;  // error: the default constructor of "Unets" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
    auto TT2 = init();
    TT2->A.predict(pic3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry it's my very first time to ask question on stackoverflow, I'm not very familiar with it's rules. Since it's the whole process I've encountered, so I didn't planned to asked in two different questions. I'll keep in mind not to make this kind of mistake next time. As for the first item, it can run correctly with tensorflow initialization declared globally like that(exe in c++). But when in switch to running in exe(c#), it just stuck.By the way, I didn't run the first exe(c++) and the second exe(c#) at the same time, so that's not the reason it couldn't work I think..

Comment: It is ok. I was thinking more that the first program (c++) was still in the process upon exit (hence holding up some resources, and preventing the second program, c#, to do proper tensorflow inference task).

Comment: I'll try to revise my code in that way.Thanks a lot for your suggestion!